# Why SelectOneMenu ignores the converter?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

I have a list of objects, a `selectOneMenu`, in which I want to display that object list. I do not want to display toString() method result in that menu, and I created a converter instead.

The problem is that in h:outputText element converter is called and I see expected value. But when I attach that converter to h:selectOneMenu, converter is still called when page is rendered, but the result is ignored and toString() result is used instead. How can I fix it?

**Some example code:**

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Priority.class)
public class PriorityConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            PriorityEJB priorityEJB = (PriorityEJB) ic.lookup("java:global/TicketSentinel/TicketSentinel-ejb/PriorityEJB");
            return priorityEJB.getPriorityByOrd(Integer.valueOf(value.charAt(0)));
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PriorityConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new ConverterException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        Priority p = (Priority) value;
        return p.getOrder() + " - " + p.getName();
    }

}
```

Part of the page:

```
<h:outputText value="Priority:" />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{ticketController.ticket.priority}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{priorityController.priorityList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Controller bean:

```
@Named(value = "priorityController")
@RequestScoped
public class PriorityController {
    @EJB
    private PriorityEJB priorityEJB;

    public List<Priority> getPriorityList() {
        return priorityEJB.getPriorities();
    }

}
```

---

**Update:**

I looked at the source of the page, and found this:

```
<td><select name="j_idt18:j_idt26" size="1">
    <option value="1 - Fatal">1 - - Fatal</option> 
    <option value="2 - Critical">2 - - Critical</option> 
    <option value="3 - Very Important">3 - - Very Important</option> 
    <option value="4 - Important">4 - - Important</option> 
    <option value="5 - Minor">5 - - Minor</option> 
    <option value="6 - Fix if time">6 - - Fix if time</option> 
    <option value="7 - Insignificant">7 - - Insignificant</option> 
</select></td>
```

So that engine prints the right value, but in the wrong place! How can I make it place the text in `value` attribute into the body of <option> block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The converter is only used to convert the *value* of the dropdown (whatever you see as `<option value>` and **not** to convert the *label* of the dropdown (whatever you see between `<option>` and `</option>`. The label is the one which is visible in the dropdown menu.

If you want to change the *label* to be the same as the value, then you just need to do it as such:

```xml
<f:selectItems value="#{priorityController.priorityList}" var="priority"
    itemValue="#{priority}" itemLabel="#{priority.order} - #{priority.name}" />
```

For the item value of `#{priority}` the converter will still be called. Although I'd prefer to use some autogenerated database ID instead of kind of a label value so that conversion is more efficient.